# DB Error: Contribution Page Uknown column 'pledge_start_date' in 'field list'

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, pledges

I have a contribution page that is set as the self-service page for pledges. When you click on the Make a Payment from the Contact Dashboard the following error occurs.

Database Error Code: Unknown column 'pledge_start_date' in 'field list', 1054
Additional Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT  id ,  status_id,scheduled_date,scheduled_amount,currency,pledge_start_date
```

FROM civicrm_pledge_payment

WHERE (  civicrm_pledge_payment.pledge_id = 6 )

[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'pledge_start_date' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT  id ,  status_id,scheduled_date,scheduled_amount,currency,pledge_start_date
 FROM civicrm_pledge_payment

WHERE (  civicrm_pledge_payment.pledge_id = 6 )

[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'pledge_start_date' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT  id ,  status_id,scheduled_date,scheduled_amount,currency,pledge_start_date
 FROM civicrm_pledge_payment

WHERE (  civicrm_pledge_payment.pledge_id = 6 )

[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'pledge_start_date' in 'field list']"]
)